# I need to write a regex that recognize all numbers with coma separated or not, excluding 4 digits numbers

Tags: python, regex, numbers

I want to capture all number with comma or not comma-separated excluding  4 digit numbers:

I want to match these numbers (in my case the number are separated by 3 digits always)

```
978,763,835,536,363
123
123,456
123456
7456
3400
```

excluding  the years like

```
1200 till 2020
```

I have written this

```
regex_patterns = [
re.compile(r'[0-9]+,?[0-9]+,?[0-9]+,?[0-9]+')
]
```

it works good ,I do not how exclude years from these number...many thanks

Of course, I am working o the sentients, the number are inside the sentences not necessity at first fo the line like this

-Thus 60 is to 41 as 100,000 is to 65,656½, the appropriate magnitude for βυ
This was found to be 36,075,5621 (with an eccentricity of 9165), corresponding to the entire oval path of Mars.
-It was 4657.

EDIT:

Since during my task I faced wit a lot of issues have updated the question a few time.

first of all the problem is mainly solved! thank you for all for the contribution.

just a very tiny issue. based on other comments I have t integrated the solution as here

```
r'(?<!\S)(?<![\d,])(?:(?!(?:1[2-9]\d\d|20[01]\d|2020))\d{4,}[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?![\d,])[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?(?!x)(?!/)
```

It can caputer most of the case correctly,

https://regex101.com/r/o5gdDt/8

then again as there is a kind of noise in my text like this:

"
I take ψο as a figured unit [x]. It's square GEOM will also be a figured unit [x2]. Add the square GEOM on εο, 227,052, and the sum of the two will be the square GEOM of ψε or ψν. But the square GEOM of βν is 4,310,747,475 PARA
"

It can not capture the number 227,052, which end with ","

when I changed it I faced with this problem

````
(?<!\S)(?<![\d,])(?:(?!(?:1[2-9]\d\d|20[01]\d|2020))\d{4,}[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?![\d])[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?(?!x)(?!/)
``` (basically ignoring comma  in (,?![\d])) 

I faced with another problem which the regex captured 4,310,747,475 in this:

4,310,747,475x2+978,763,835,536,363


as you see here..
https://regex101.com/r/o5gdDt/9
any idea would be very appreciated 

however the regex now works almost good, but in order to be perfect I need to improve it





-
````

Comment: regexes aren't good to compare numerical values. Perform a post-processing instead

Comment: Your problem is that you only understand a little bit about how regex works, I suggest finding a regex tutorial and learning more than the bare basics

Comment: Also, while you can do this with regex you really shouldn't. Matching numbers is one thing, but why would you throw in an arbitrary date range?

Comment: I hope you aren't thinking that the numbers 0 to 999 don't refer to years that historians might want to talk about, or that numbers 10000 and onward don't refer to years that science fiction authors might want to talk about.

Comment: Excluding 4 digit numbers is `(?:[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]{5,})(?:,(?:[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]{5,}))+`

Comment: @watson I am familiar with regex. I mean I already worked with that, of course, it has a deeper level that I am not aware

Comment: @watzon  because I have an old text. It has 4 digit numbers betwenn 1100 till 1700  mainly referred to years, I already captured those as a date!  so I only want to have 3  digits numbers, more than 5 number digits..of course, better and hard plus the number from 1700 till 9999 or..

Comment: @Karl Knechtel  in my special case and context, I do not have such a problem

Comment: What about `123456,123456` or `1,2,3,4` or `1,23,456,7890`?

Comment: @Toto we do not have such non-standard numbers in the text. we have number separated by three digits like 12,345 - 145,789 4,325. we also have 4567 which is not separated by 3 digits that all! I want to exclude a period of time which is somehow between 1200 till 1700 more or less

Answer (score 2):

If excluding all 4 digit number years its this

`\b(?!\d{4}\b)[0-9]+(?:,(?!\d{4}\b)[0-9]+)*\b`

https://regex101.com/r/T3L3X5/1

If excluding just the number years between 1200 and 2020 its this

`\b(?!(?:12\d{2}|1[3-9]\d{2}|20[01]\d|2020)\b)[0-9]+(?:,(?!(?:12\d{2}|1[3-9]\d{2}|20[01]\d|2020)\b)[0-9]+)*\b`

https://regex101.com/r/ZuC6LR/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex to match one to three digit numbers and optionally also match any subsequent numbers that are comma separated but don't have more than 3 digits.

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/T6sNUs/1/

The explanation goes like this,

- `\b` - marks word boundary to avoid matching partially in a larger number then 3 digits
- `\d{1,3}` - matches one to three digit number
- `(?:,\d{1,3})*` - non-capturing group optionally matches comma separated number having one to three digits
- `\b` - again marks word boundary to avoid matching partially in a larger number then 3 digits

Edit: For requirement mentioned in comments, where numbers with at least three or more digits optionally separated by comma should match. But it should reject the match if any of the numbers present in the line lies from 1200 to 2020.

This regex should give you what you need,

```
^(?!.*\b(?:1[2-9]\d\d|20[01]\d|2020)\b)\d{3,}(?:,\d{3,})*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T6sNUs/2/)

Please confirm if this works for you, so I can add explanation to above regex.

And in case you want it to restrict it from 1200 to 1800 as you mentioned in your comments, you can use this regex,

```
^(?!.*\b(?:1[2-7]\d\d|1800)\b)\d{3,}(?:,\d{3,})*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T6sNUs/3/)

Comment: that works perfectly good, tnx,but unfortunately in the book, we have also 4 digits numbers like 4756 which should be included, but with this code can not. I am working on that

Comment: @DevML: Ok, I can handle that as well if you can tell what all four digit numbers you want to exclude. Will it be correct to say as per your post that you want to exclude numbers from 1200 till 2020?

Comment: I want to have all number (from 3 digit to more) with or without  coma and exclude all number referred to years in the book starting from for instance 1200 till 1800 this is my guess

Comment: many thanks. the last one was almost good but can not capture 5670  or 7700 or 5657 .it could capture those with comma 4,567 but not without a comma

Comment: @DevML: Ok, as per your given requirements in your updated post, let me come up with an appropriate regex.

Comment: @ Silvanas does not work? the problem with the last code is that capture one or 2 digit number, which is not desired plus does not capture 4 digit numbers 7756

Comment: @DevML: Did you try my updated regex solution. That should work for you. Please check the regex101 demo link.

Comment: I have tried that, it seems it only works on v3 of regex. you can see that https://regex101.com/r/T6sNUs/1 does not work. I also tried on my python code.it deos not work...I could find my version regex ...it is only written 2018.1.10 ,could be related to update of regex?

Comment: even so, It does not work for 12,345 https://regex101.com/r/T6sNUs/2  :)

Comment: @DevML: Hey I misunderstood your post. I was rejecting input if any of the parts in your text contained number less than two. Check this https://regex101.com/r/T6sNUs/5/

Comment: @DevML: Could you check if my last demo is working for your all cases? If not, can you tell what do you need further?

Answer (score 1):

This is matching all your test cases:

```
(?<![\d,])(?:(?!(?:1[2-9]\d\d|20[01]\d|2020))\d{4,}|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?![\d,])
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<![\d,])              # negative lookbehind, make we haven't digit or comma before
  (?:                   # non capture group
    (?!                 # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
      (?:               # non capture group
        1[2-9]\d\d      # range 1200 -> 1999
       |                # OR
        20[01]\d        # range 2000 -> 2019
       |                # OR
        2020            # 2020
      )                 # end group
    )                   # end lookahead
    \d{4,}              # 4 or more digits
   |                    # OR
    \d{1,3}             # 1 up to 3 digits
    (?:,\d{3})*         # non capture group, a comma and 3 digits, 0 or more times
  )                     # end group
(?![\d,])               # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't digit or comma after
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o5gdDt/7)

Comment: thank you for the response, I see that you have put a lot of time, but still does not work. Imagine this number 12,600 it only captures last three digits! see here https://regex101.com/r/o5gdDt/2

Comment: @DevML: Sorry, I don't get you. [It doesn't capture last 3 digits in `12,600`] it doesn't match at all. Would you like the regex match `12,600`? It is not according to your request: “in my case the number are separated by 3 digits always)”

Comment: @ it only catches 600 in 12,600 which is not desired! 12,600 is only separated by 3 digits but the code only catch 600!

Comment: @DevML: Sorry but it doesn't match, I don't understand what you are saying.. The regex clearly matches all list of 3 digits coma separated or any number with more than 3 digits except range 1200-2020. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DevML: I think I understand your real needs, You want to match in a text, not only digits alone. See my edit with new demo link. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final answer that I got with using the comments and integrating according my context:

https://regex101.com/r/o5gdDt/8

As you see this code

```
(?<!\S)(?<![\d,])(?:(?!(?:1[2-9]\d\d|20[01]\d|2020))\d{4,}[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?![\d,])[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?(?!x)(?!/)
```

can capture all digits which sperated by 3 digits in text like

- "here is 100,100"
- "23,456"
- "1,435"

all more than 4 digit number like without comma separated

- 2345
- 1234 " here is 123456"

also this kind of number

- 65,656½
- 65,656½,
- 23,123½

The only tiny issue here is if there is a comma(dot) after the first two types it can not capture those. for example, it can not capture

- "here is 100,100,"
- "23,456,"
- "1,435,"

unfortunately there is a few number intext which ends with comma...can someone gives me an idea of how to modify this to capture above also?

I have tried to do it and modified version is so:

```
(?<!\S)(?<![\d,])(?:(?!(?:1[2-9]\d\d|20[01]\d|2020))\d{4,}[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?![\d])[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]?(?!x)(?!/)
```

basically I delete comma in (?![\d,]) but it causes to another problem in my context 
it captures part of a number that is part of equation like this :

4,310,747,475x2
 57,349,565,416,398x.

see here:

https://regex101.com/r/o5gdDt/10

I know that is kind of special question I would be happy to know your ides

Comment: @Toto  I would be happy with your comments regarding this , many thanks

Comment: @Silvanas  I would be happy with your comments regarding this, many thanks

Comment: @Ines Montani I would be happy with your comments regarding this, many thanks